# How can you play friends in ranked matches on Soul Calibur IV?

Tags: soul-calibur-4

I finally figured out how to do it on non-ranked matches. However, when I make a ranked match and push triangle, nothing happens. So, how do I play my friends to also get ranking? Otherwise I feel like I'm just wasting time if I'm playing but have nothing to show for it.

Comment: Usually a game with ranked multiplayer wouldn't let you play against your friends, to prevent you and your friends from cheating to achieve high rankings (e.g. Letting each other win to increase stats). I will assume this is the case here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify your opponent in a ranked game because that would allow people to 'cheat' the ranking system by simply having your friend allow you to win again and again.

Comment: thanks. i didn't want to 'cheat' the ranking system. Actually I just wanted to play friends and actually get points for it. Otherwise I feel like I'm wasting time.